# ¿Cómo generar los . class de un proyecto desde IntelliJ con JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, class, compilar

Holas.

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi proyecto, es viejo y me lo entregaron, no tiene gestor de tareas como Gradle o Maven. Necesito generar los .class del proyecto en IntelliJ con el JDK 1.5, pero por más configuraciones que hago me lo sigue generando con 1.8.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Debería haber una forma de cambiar el JDK, ¿ya le echaste un vistazo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987228/how-do-i-change-the-intellij-idea-default-jdk ?

Comment: @FernandoCarraro gracias por responder. Ya he intentado hacer lo que aparece en el link pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. ¿Alguna otra idea que se te ocurra?